# Github for windows 8 failing to clone repo

Tags: windows, github, github-for-windows

Tried reinstalling and can't seem to do it.
Here is the log message:

```
2013-09-13 10:52:39.0807|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel|Cloning repo  https://github.com/MattMcFarland/hvac-hacks.git
2013-09-13 10:52:39.0807|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Helpers.GitRemote|Cloning 'https://github.com/MattMcFarland/hvac-hacks.git' to 'hvac-hacks' in directory 'D:\Dropbox\GDT\My Documents\GitHub
2013-09-13 10:52:39.0837|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.PortableGit.Helpers.GitEnvironment|Process set up with this SSH Agent info: 8760:/tmp/ssh-GqkyFs8464/agent.8464
2013-09-13 10:52:39.0837|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.PortableGit.Helpers.GitEnvironment|PATH is C:\Users\conta_000\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\cmd;C:\Users\conta_000\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\bin;C:\Users\conta_000\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RYZ6Q7YO.4O9\74Q512X5.JXP\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0001.0000_0b5f24f8a60558d4;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\System32
2013-09-13 10:52:39.0837|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.IO.ObservableProcess|Starting: Process - Id: '(unknown)', Name: '(unknown)', FileName: 'C:\Users\conta_000\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\bin\git.exe', Args: 'clone --progress --recursive  --  "https://github.com/MattMcFarland/hvac-hacks.git" "hvac-hacks" '
2013-09-13 10:52:39.1017|WARN|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.StandardUserErrors|Showing user error Please check your internet connection.
    GitHub.IO.ProcessException: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'hvac-hacks'.: Permission denied
2013-09-13 10:52:41.7220|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Deactivating GitHub.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.
2013-09-13 10:52:41.7220|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Deactivating GitHub.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel.
2013-09-13 10:52:41.7220|INFO|thread:1|GitHub.Extensions.ReactiveScreen|Closed GitHub.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel.
```

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Where are you trying to create the cloned repo?

Comment: I'm just using github for windows, can't seem to find a way to set the dir for cloned repo??

Comment: It's My Documents\GitHub

Comment: Changed it to my user dir and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target directory needed to be changed. The app didnt have permissions to use the default My Docs folder. Most likely because I have My Docs on a different HDD for space saving reasons...

Comment: I'm getting something similar.

It gets ALL THE FILEs, and at the end FAILED TO CLONE, CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION.

It happens with a private repo that has been shared to me, any other of my own repos are working,